# Mandrill application - what is it and what does its api key do

Tags: mandrill

Mandrill has an application area where they allow you to add applications.

I added an application and got an API key. What do I do with it? I already have an API key from the `SMTP & API Credentials` tab. What's an "application"?

Answer (score -1):

Application is any app you wrote by yourself or that came from any other provider. For example, it can be a webapp in your site. You can access Mandrill interface from API only by providing your key -- it is your "password".